# Interpretation of Dynkin diagrams

Tags: string-theory, mathematical-physics, lie-algebra, branes

I am having trouble in understanding the physics represented by dynkin diagrams. Say I have the following diagram:

[image: Dynkin diagram]

- What is the difference between the square nodes and circular nodes?
- What does the number inside the nodes represent?
- How can I find the gauge group of the quiver from the diagram?

I know that each node corresponds to a factor U(N) of the gauge group, but I am not sure how to proceed.

Comment: Did you find an answer?  I'm only familiar with the Dynkin diagrams for the classical series, and so quite curious to see what your beast is.